# What is wrong with the word "motorsporting"?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

I was reading a book where the author is discussing the BBC buying the rights to show Formula 1. He quotes the press release by the BBC announcing the acquisition.

The book's quote is "the biggest motorsporting [sic] event is returning home after 12 years".

What is wrong with "motorsporting" here? I googled "motorsporting event" and got almost 6,000 results, so it seems to be used fairly commonly.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with it? English verbs nouns all the time.

Comment: @Robusto Because they used [sic] and he's wondering why.

Comment: @Phil: I thought that was his insertion. If it's from the book, then it indicates that some fussbudget *thinks* there is something wrong with verbing that noun, but they're wrong.

Comment: Obviously, the author does not approve of nounverbing.

Comment: If the author does not wish to be known as a [sporting writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_James_Apperley), this is a good way to do it. Anyway, it would appear to be the direct descendant of  *sporting* as it pertains to [hunting, horse racing and other manly pursuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sporting_Magazine) ;). [One more that's just too fun not to link to](http://www.sfmuseum.org/hist11/firstwomansporting.html)

Comment: Please identify the book. We are kind of fussy about citing the source of material here.

Comment: Is it just verbing? It looks kind of like a verbed noun that has then been adjectivized...

Comment: @1006a Adding "ing" is how you turn a verb into a noun. So it's an adjectivized nounified verbified noun.

Comment: Since sports involve activities where you do something (such as fence) and you then have to name the activity (fencing), gerunds are common in the names of sports and so divergent opinions can arise. Since the -ing form can also be a participle it can easily be thought of as an adjective, leading to further opinions. But on top of these there is the strange phenomenon of these English gerunds being used in other languages giving them an extra flavour in something that is inherently international when foreigners use them not quite right in English.

Comment: Examples are [Sporting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporting_CP),  [bowling](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bowling), [ camping](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camping)

Answer (score 1):

The author probably believes the quoted text should have been written as:

> the biggest motorsport event is returning home after 12 years

Not wanting to take responsibilty for this oversight, he/she put **[sic]** in there to preserve his/her reputation as an impeccable linguist.

People generally have issues with nouns that have been freshly-verbed.  I personally still have problems with **impacted** being a replacement for affected/effected, but I'm stubborn and old-fashioned that way.

Comment: The issue isn't just that it's a verbified noun, but it's a noun being used as a verb being used as a noun being used as an adjective. "sporting" is the gerund of "sport" being used as a verb (and the gerund is the noun form of a verb), but "sport" is already a noun, so you can just use "sport", rather than turning it into a verb and then using the noun form of that verb. It's like saying "arting gallery" instead of "art gallery".

Comment: Yes, it's a bit like the, completely unnecessary and ill-defined, verb "to leverage" which is one of my pet hates.